# Json_decode unix timestamp

Tags: php, unix, json

I have a database that holds when items were uploaded.
This stores the codes in a unix format    `1304480324000`
When pulling the data out and restoring them into arrays using `json_decode($output, true)`
It converts my nice unix format timestamp into `1.304480324E+12`

Is there a way to convert it back or preventing this from happening?"

Answer (score 0):

You don't have UNIX time there (which uses whole second)... that's a full millisecond representation of time.

You need to divide it by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same number, just in a different representation. It's too large for an integer, so it's stored as a float in memory. There's plenty of precision to hold it, so just manipulate it as normal.

Comment: Yeah i found out its a float, was coming back to change this and saw your post haha. Still in dire need of figuring out how to change it back as if it were a unix timestamp code.

e.g. 1.304480324E+12 = 1304480324000
floatval($var); doesn't work, so any solutions? :/

Comment: There are no solutions because there is no problem other than it doesn't look pretty. Format it appropriately on output.

Comment: How can i use the new float variable? it's messing with me and can't figure out how to convert it to get the date.

Comment: First you convert it to seconds. Then you run it through `strftime()`.

Comment: Javascript timestamps are in milliseconds, so just divide by 1000 to get a unix timestamp. They're otherwise functionally identical - seconds (or milliseconds) since Jan 1 1970.